# urllib.urlretrieve stops download when no activity on Tkinter window on Mac only

Tags: python, macos, user-interface, download, tkinter

I'm trying to make a file downloader with a Tkinter GUI window, which will download a file using the following line:

```
 urllib.urlretrieve(url = fileurl, filename = file, reporthook = progBar)
```

Progbar is a progress bar on my Tkinter GUI window. When I run my code on Windows, the download works fine and runs normally, as does the progress bar.

However, when I run the same code on a Mac, the download and progress bar will only progress if there is activity in the Tkinter GUI window. For example, if the window is in the background, the download will pause until the window is clicked on. Even then, when the Tkinter GUI window is not in the background, the download will only progress if I am doing something like moving the mouse around the screen or repeatedly pressing buttons on the keyboard, otherwise the download pauses again. It seems like it is timing out for some reason, and I'm not sure how to fix this or why it only happens on Mac and not windows.

If I put a print statement in the progBar method, the download also slows down.

I have also tried removing the reporthook argument from the call to urllib.urlretrieve, when I do this the download progresses fine.

My progBar method is as follows:

```
def progBar(blocks, blocksize, totalsize) :
 global pb
 bytesdownloaded = blocksize*blocks
 mbdownloaded = bytesdownloaded/1024/1024
 mbsize = float(blocksize)/float(totalsize)
 totalsize = totalsize/1024/1024
 percent = mbsize*100
 global v
 va.set("(" + str(mbdownloaded) + 'MB out of ' + str(totalsize) + 'MB)')
 pb.step(percent)
```

I am using Python 2.7 if this helps.

**Edit:** for further information, the download (call to urllib.urlretrieve) is performed in a background thread, while the GUI window is meant to be the main thread. This may have something to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a guess, but it's possible that the UI output command in the reporthook is hanging due to the fact that the event loop is (I'm guessing) paused for a program when it's in the background. I have vague recollection of the Tkinter UI model but one solution might be to set some global variable with your current progress in the hook, and have UI paint it separately - do not issue UI commands in the hook.

Comment: I attempted this - removing the lines `va.set("(" + str(mbdownloaded) + 'MB out of ' + str(totalsize) + 'MB)')` and 
`pb.step(percent)` causes the download to progress fine. I'm not sure how I'd get these to update somewhere else, if not in the reporthook call... I thought this was the whole point of the reporthook.

Comment: You can try updating by polling the global variable and paining the progress bar accordingly.